# RESTEasy gives NoClassDefFoundError for HeaderParameterParser

Tags: google-chrome, rest, websphere, resteasy

I have written simple RESTEasy Hello World web-service. It used to work just fine when invoked from IE or from within Eclipse(RAD), but when I hit it from Google Chrome, it used give Exception saying.

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception thrown by servlet RestEasy: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resteasy/util/HeaderParameterParser
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.delegates.MediaTypeHeaderDelegate.parse(MediaTypeHeaderDelegate.java:57)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.delegates.MediaTypeHeaderDelegate.fromString(MediaTypeHeaderDelegate.java:18)
at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:150)
at org.jboss.resteasy.util.MediaTypeHelper.parseHeader(MediaTypeHelper.java:203)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletUtil.extractAccepts(ServletUtil.java:120)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletUtil.extractHttpHeaders(ServletUtil.java:83)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:186)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
```

But now this Exception is occurring in all the cases.

I am sure that the jar file containing **HeaderParameterParser** class which is restreasy-jaxrs2.2.3.GA.jar is on the classpath.

I am using

- RESTEasy 2.2.3.GA(also tried with 3.o.1Final).
- Websphere Application Server v8.0
- RAD 8.0
- Maven

Comment: Can you look at the headers being passed and see what might be different coming from Chrome? Either by logging at the server or using a proxy or network trace of some sort.

Comment: @Nils, were you able to solve this one?

Comment: @Nils,i am facing the same issue. you got some solution?